# Did the author omit 'to be correct' after 'turn out' in the last sentence?

Tags: usage

Otherwise, I am not quite sure I understand how ***turn out*** is used in the sentence.
According to dictionaries, when ***turn out*** is used as intransitive verb, it means 'appear', which doesn't make sense in the context, as it means 'predictions appear'.

> Some beginning researchers mistakenly believe that a good hypothesis
> is one that is guaranteed to be right (e.g., alcohol will slow down
> reaction time). However, if we already know your hypothesis is true
> before you test it, test- ing your hypothesis won’t tell us anything
> new (as Einstein said, “A person who never made a mistake never tried
> anything new”). Remember, research is supposed to produce new
> knowledge. To get new knowledge, you, as a researcher–explorer, need
> to leave the safety of the shore (established facts) and venture into
> uncharted waters (as Einstein said, “If we knew what we were doing, it
> would not be called research, would it?”). If your predictions about
> what will happen in these uncharted waters is wrong, that’s okay:
> Scientists are allowed to make mistakes (as Bates said, “Research is
> the pro- cess of going up alleys to see if they are blind”). Indeed,
> scientists often learn more from predictions that do not ***turn
> out*** than from those that do.

[Research Design Explained](https://psikologi.unmuha.ac.id/wp-content/uploads/2020/02/Research-Design-Explained.pdf)

Comment: It could use an extra word, but if predictions do not appear, they do not show up as predicted. A good thing to learn from. Here, *turn out* means succeed.

Comment: It's certainly an "uncommon, non-standard" usage (arguably **sub**-standard). But [*scientists often learn more from predictions that **do not turn out** than from those that do*.](https://www.google.com/search?tbm=bks&q=%22predictions+that+do+not+turn+out+than+from%22)

Comment: I strongly suspect that some of these "Einstein" quotes were not said by Einsteen

Answer (score 1):

The phrase "turn out" can mean a lot of things in different contexts. In this context, you're correct that you can read this as if it says "from predictions that do not turn out to be correct." The phrase is common enough that it can be shortened and still understood, so the end part is often omitted.

I think that I would more generally define "turn out" to be referring to the end of something, most likely a process or event.

Some other examples of "turn out" in a natural sounding context:

- It **turned out** that I had more time for the project than I thought I did, so I finished it easily.
- I am writing a new piece of music. I don't know if I like it yet; we'll see how it **turns out**.
- My new kitten is too wild! I hope she will **turn out** calmer than she is now.

The common meaning here is that they are all related to a process or event ending.

### Another Meaning of "Turn Out"

You also might encounter this phrase used in a different way. As a slang term, "turn out" can refer to a group of people who show up to an event.

- This party really has a great **turn out**. There must be more than 100 people here.
- The city **turned out** for the political rally. This candidate will surely win the election.
- My store's opening event didn't have such a good **turn out**. Only a few customers came.